# OpenEmbedded - determine which packages changed

Tags: openembedded, bitbake, yocto

I am working with OpenEmbedded (Daisy) and trying to come up with a way to create a tarball of just the packages that have changed between two versions of a build. Is there a straight forward way to determine which packages have been rebuilt between two subsequent builds?

For example, I have a build that creates a specific image for a specific machine. I install that image onto the target. I then make updates to the source for package x which happens to be a library. It turns out that package y depends on package x and also gets rebuilt. I want to create a tarball that has just the ipk's for package x & y. I can then take this tarball and transfer it to the target machine and use the package manager "opkg" to install just those two packages.

Any ideas or suggestions on an approach if OE doesn't natively support doing something like this would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

Enable buildhistory and you'll have a convenient git repository of what was build and lots of metadata.